# MySQL from_unixtime now and midnight

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

The following query will produce a unix time with today's date:

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()-0)*1000   --> in millisecond

How would I get one that will display unix time until midnight? I know I can do close-open interval like this:

```
WHERE ctime  >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()-0)*1000 
  AND ctime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()+1)*1000
```

The reason I need this is because I want to run the below SP and simply pass the number of days as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_report_q1``(IN Day1 INT(5))
BEGIN
.
.
.
WHERE  ctime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()-Day1)*1000 and ctime < **DAY1 UNTIL MIDNIGHT**
```

Hope this is clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use artithmetics here:

```
where 
        ctime >= (unix_timestamp(current_date) - day1 * 60 * 60 * 24) * 1000 
    and ctime <  (unix_timestamp(current_date) - (day1 - 1) * 60 * 60 * 24) * 1000
```

Or with intervals:

```
where 
        ctime >= (unix_timestamp(current_date - interval day1 day) * 1000 
    and ctime <  (unix_timestamp(current_date) - interval (day1 - 1) day) * 1000
```